# Convert ListMultimap to list of keys with duplicates?

Tags: java, multimap

So I have a `ListMultimap<Integer, String>` that I want to convert to a `List<Integer>` that contains duplicates of the same `Integer` if there was >1 value associated with a `Integer` key in the `ListMultimap`. For instance, if:

`ListMultimap<Integer, String> myMap = {2 -> "foo", 3 -> ("bar1, bar2")}`

I want my resultant `List<Integer>` to look like: `[2, 3, 3]`. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is Guava, this is just the one line

```
Lists.newArrayList(multimap.keys())
```

or, if you have an `ImmutableListMultimap`,

```
multimap.keys().asList()
```

(Note here that `Multimap.keys()` is a `Multiset<Integer>`, which iterates over elements exactly in the way you want -- that is, it will have one occurrence of each key for each value associated with that key.)

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes it would.  Note that we're referring to `keys()`, which is a `Multiset<K>`, as opposed to `keySet()`, which is a `Set<K>`.

Comment: Yes. I just saw my mistake and deleted my comment. +1.

Comment: Great, thank you for the concise one line solution! Beats iterating through the Multiset!